# Writing in file and saving it from Save as dialog through javascript

Tags: javascript, dialog, modal-dialog

Below code is working fine to write XML data into a file.

```
function btnSave_onclick() {
var aFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
aTS = aFSO.OpenTextFile(FilePath,2,true);
aTS.Write (XMLText.value);
aTS.Close();
}
```

I want to change this code to show a dialog box to saveAs in desired location.

I found below code to open save as dialog box

```
document.execCommand('SaveAs','true',filename.txt);
```

Now question is how can I save data (which is in XMLText.value) through This dialog.

Is there any other way to save data trogh dialogBox. It is for IE

In other way Is it possible to provide a Browse button to select desired location in c: drive or any other drive and by saying ok get that path and store in a variable and by using above code can save directly to that  location.

But here question is how to provide browse button?